# Error while setting targetConnectionFactory in UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-boot, spring-jms

We are receiving a compilation error in the following code, while trying to set the targetConnectionFactory.

According to the example given in [Spring 4 documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html) for UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, the setTargetConnectionFactory() method takes the object of JndiObjectFactoryBean as an argument. But, looks like the JndiObjectFactoryBean hasn't implemented the 'ConnectionFactory' interface, which is supposed to be the argument of this set method.

***Is this any bug with Spring 4 ? if JndiObjectFactoryBean object cannot be set as targetConnectionFactory , then what can be used in it's place ?***

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean theJndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
theJndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(getJNDITemplate());
theJndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(jndiConnectionFactoryName);
UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter theUserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
theUserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(theJndiObjectFactoryBean);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference between your code and the example is in the XML config example that myTargetConnectionFactory is actually a bean managed by Spring. You aren't doing that. You are just creating a new object Spring doesn't know about. The magic happens when setting the targetConnectionFactory of myConnectionFactory. Even though it *looks* like the type if JndiObjectFactoryBean, Spring is actually injecting the underlying connectionFactory created by the factory bean.

The java config equivalent would be you creating a @Bean that returns the JndiObjectFactoryBean and another having another bean for UserCredentialsConnetionFactoryAdapter that depends on a ConnectionFactory.

Comment: Let's say i am autowiring an object of the JndiObjectFactoeyBean , and then use that here in my CoE, will it work ? Or should i inject this object into user credentials connection factory bean ?

Comment: I was more just trying to answer the question as it was asked to help understand the spring docs. Sometimes xml to java config doesn't always look the same. You can probably just do this theUserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory( (ConnectionFactory)theJndiObjectFactorBean.getObject());

Comment: This approach resolved the compilation error but, now the theJndiObjectFactorBean.getObject() seems to be returning NULL and resulting in an assertion error saying targetConnectionFactory cannot be set as NULL in UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter. I see that the getObject() will return a Singleton object. How can i initialize this singleton object before getObject() ?

Comment: i invoked afterPropertiesSet() before calling the getObject() , i guess this initializes and now i see that the code is trying to do a look-up to the JNDI name. I am facing few other unrelated errors (of missing JARs). Will update the solution once this issue resolves.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced a very similar issue while trying to convert from XML config to beans and 
 I've found the right answer was in the comments (thanks!), but it wasn't clear enough.

To handle the mismatch, you need to get the object from JndiObjectFactoryBean and cast it to the appropiate type.

`connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory)targetConnectionFactory.getObject());`